# How to import table from RDBMS into HDFS in Zebra format using Sqoop?

Tags: oracle, formatting, rdbms, hdfs, sqoop

Sqoop helps to copy data between relational database (e.g. Oracle DB) and Hadoop.

But how can I make it store data in Zebra format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop do not support Zebra format at the moment. I would encourage you to file a new [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP) asking for such support.

Comment: BTW, is Sqoop 1.99 version development of 1.4.2 or are they parallel (like mess in Hadoop versions) ?

Comment: Sqoop have currently two main lines, stable Sqoop 1 (1.4.2) and experimental Sqoop2 that is currently in version 1.99.1. So they are actually parallel.